# application still exists in memory although it is closed

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2` and in `Form1` I wrote the following code:

```
#include "Form2"
//
//
Form2^ obj = gcnew Form2();
obj->Show();
this->Hide();
//
//
```

The problem is when I close the screen of `Form2` by the X button, the application still exists in memory because the base form `Form1` is hidden only but is not closed. What can I do?

Comment: You've answered your own question - it's only Hidden, where as you need to close/dispose of it.

Comment: Call Application::Exit() in the Form2 FormClosed event.

Comment: @HansPassant: it doesn't work, it is compiled well but no effect.

Comment: @HansPassant: I think the problem is I dirctly wrote `Form2_FormClosed{ Application::Exit(); }` without decleration! How can I declare it before I use!

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans, I solved the problem, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it based on HansPassant comment. First, need to declare Form2_FormClosed as an event handler like:

```
this->FormClosed += gcnew FormClosedEventHandler(this, &Form2::Form2_FormClosed);
```

then use it like:

```
private: System::Void Form2_FormClosed(){ 
Application::Exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close underlaying form on exit.

Try to overwrite `OnClosing` method in `Form2` and force `From1` to close then with `Close` method..

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is because your parent or first form is still Open, you just have hide that, you should use obj.ShowDialog() function, it will open the 2nd form as popup and 1st form will not be accessible...until 2nd form is closed...

Another way to do this is to use System.Diagnotics namespace and use processes class, and get all instance of your application and then end process programatically...
Like this...
using System.Diagnostics;

```
private Process GetaProcess(string processname)
{
Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);

if (aProc.Length > 0)
return aProc[0];

else return null;
}
 Process myprc = Call GetaProcess("Your_app_process_name.exe"); myprc.Kill();
```

Comment: Can you please convert your code to `C++/CLI`, also How can I put that code to be executed when I press X button?

Comment: Thats only workaround, the more elegant way is to take reference to parent form and close it...